# Neural net giving different outputs for same input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have neural network class that I have trained already and saved the weights after pickling. It is a generator neural network (as in GANs) where it takes a multivariate gaussian (noise) vector as input and outputs a vector that is of interest (parameter vector). Here is the declaration of the class:

```
class MLP():
    def __init__(self, cond_class, min_x, max_x, n_samples, NAMES_km, param_fixing,noise_input):
        self.latent_dim = int(configs['MLP']['latent_dim'])
        print(self.latent_dim)
        self.cond_class = cond_class
        self.min_x = min_x
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.label_shape = 1
        self.param_fixing = param_fixing
        self.names_km = NAMES_km
        self.noise = noise_input

        self.n_samples = n_samples
        self.n_parameters = int(configs['MLP']['no_kms'])
        self.param_shape = self.n_parameters

        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        # Build and compile the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()
        self.generator.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
                               optimizer=optimizer)
        # self.generator.summary()
        # The generator takes noise and the target label as input
        # and generates the corresponding digit of that label
        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape=(self.label_shape,))
        param = self.generator([noise, label])

    def build_generator(self):

        # get architecture from config
        layer_1 = int(configs['MLP']['layer_1'])
        layer_2 = int(configs['MLP']['layer_2'])
        layer_3 = int(configs['MLP']['layer_3'])

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(layer_1, input_dim=self.latent_dim + self.label_shape))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(Dense(layer_2))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(Dense(layer_3))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(Dense(self.n_parameters))  # , activation = 'tanh'))

        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape=(self.label_shape,))

        model_input = concatenate([noise, label])

        param = model(model_input)

        return Model([noise, label], param)

    def sample_parameters(self):

        # we just try to generate stable models
        
        sampled_labels = np.ones(self.n_samples).reshape(-1, 1) * self.cond_class

        if(len(self.noise) == 0):
            self.noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (self.n_samples, self.latent_dim))
        
        gen_par = self.generator.predict([self.noise , sampled_labels])
        # Rescale parameters according to previous scaling on X_train
        x_new, new_min, new_max = hp.unscale_range(gen_par, np.min(gen_par), np.max(gen_par), self.min_x, self.max_x)

        if self.param_fixing:
            return self.param_fixer(x_new),self.noise 
        else:
            return x_new,self.noise
```

Now when I try to take a saved input vector (a noise file) and a saved weight (a .pkl file) and load the weights and try to recreate the output like so,

```
old_noise = np.load('noise_0.npy')
path_to_weights = 'weights_0.pkl'
new_noise = []
idx_to_choose = 20
n_sets = 10
for _ in range(n_sets):
    new_noise.append(old_noise[idx_to_choose])    
new_noise = np.array(new_noise)


mlp = MLP(cond_class, lnminkm, lnmaxkm, n_sets, names_km,pf_flag, new_noise)

# Load saved weights and generate
opt_weights = hp.load_pkl(path_to_weights)
mlp.generator.set_weights(opt_weights)
gen_params, _ = mlp.sample_parameters()
```

the output vector (generated parameter vector) is the not the same as the previous one. Moreover, even though the same input noise is being used for n_sets number of times I get weird behavior in some of the components of the output vector, for e.g,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msTJN.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAEui.jpg)

overall, 10 among the 274 components of the output vector have mild oscillations for the same noise input while others dont.

I have tried several different weights from the same and different repeats of training but the issue seems to be persistent. I have also tried different conda environments and dockers but to no success. Any help would be appreciated.